# Trigger to Automatically insert in same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know can we make a Trigger on a table to update a column of newly inserted row

And that column data will be related by a formula to the same column in previous row

Please let me know....

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you need a Trigger which is after insert. It should look something like this:

`CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON table_name FOR EACH ROW trigger_body`

Cheers

LK